# Button, on click change text (2sec), reset while clicked in this time window

Tags: jquery

I would like to give the button of a form a little animation. When I click the "order" button I want to change the color and the text for 2 second. After 2 seconds it will return to it's original state. When I click the button again in this 2 second window I would like to reset the rotation. Atm its working when I click it once. But when I click 2 or 3 times quickly It doesnt work. Pls look below for what I got so far. My main question is how can I change my code so even click multiple times wont break it.

A little side question:
In my code I have the text sliding in from the bottom, is it possible to let it slide in from the top?

```js
var timerId, delay = 2000; 
$(".product-form").submit(function(e){

  var button = $(this).find('button[type=submit]'),
      order = button.find("span:eq(0)"),
      added = button.find("span:eq(1)");

  clearTimeout(timerId);
  added.hide();
  order.hide();
  button.addClass("green");
  added.slideDown("slow");

  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    added.hide();
    order.show();
    button.removeClass("green");
  }, delay); 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: orange;
}

.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake, you are creating ***"timerId"*** inside the callback. Everytime you click. It will create new var, not clear the time. Please check logic. Else use match css, if already green is added return dnt call settimeout.

https://codepen.io/deepakshrma/pen/QrBVgQ

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
    <button><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin hidden"></i>Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
  <button><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin hidden" ></i>Submit</button>

</div>

.alert button > i.hidden {
  display: none;
} 
.alert button > i.loading {
  display: inline-block;
} 

let selected = null;
$(".alert button").click(function (event) {
  if(selected){
    if( selected === $(this)){
      return;
    }else {
      selected.find('i').removeClass('loading')
      selected = $(this);
      selected.find('i').addClass('loading')
    }
  }else {
    selected = $(this);
    selected.find('i').addClass('loading')
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    selected.find('i').removeClass('loading')
  }, 2000)
  console.log($(this))
});
```

Comment: you’re right. I have another question I hope you can help me again. When I have 2 of these forms with the same class name, I click on form 1, and then immediately on form 2, form 1 doesn’t go back to his default state. Do you know how I can fix that? I updated my example.

Comment: You can solve using a map or outer scope var. See example below. I updated answer.

https://codepen.io/deepakshrma/pen/QrBVgQ

Comment: I accepted the answer, because it solved my initial problem. However, the problem with multiple forms (same class name) isn’t solved yet. In your example, I can’t click multiple times on the same button. I have to wait until rotation of the first click is completed. Is it possible to click multiple times on the same button and that multiple forms work separately without blocking the rest?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".product-form").submit(function(e){

  var timerId, delay = 2000; 
  var button = $(this).find('button[type=submit]'),
      order = button.find("span:eq(0)"),
      added = button.find("span:eq(1)");

  if(button.attr('disable')) {
     return false;
  }
  else {
     button.attr({'disable': 'true'});
  }
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  added.hide();
  order.hide();
  button.addClass("green");
  added.slideDown("slow");

  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    added.hide();
    order.show();
    button.removeClass("green");
    button.removeAttr('disable');   /// Note : if you are click multiple times   
    button.attr({'enable': 'true'});/// duplicate data's will be added.
  }, delay); 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

try it

If button is disabled I'll return the code.